# How to start two animations at same time in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have two linear layouts which I want to perform two different animation on both of these layouts and at the same time.

Now its working in sequential manner. i.e, after completing one its starting another.

here is my code.

```
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
            inFromRight.setDuration(500);
            inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
            outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
            outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.menu:
                            mainLayout.startAnimation(outtoLeft);
                sideBar.startAnimation(inFromRight);                
                break;
            }
        }

outtoLeft.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mainLayout
                        .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40));

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it your entire code? The way it's written both animations should start at the same time.

Comment: No, I have animation listeners also. After completing one animation I am performing some other UI operations, is that affects..? I have updated the code.

Answer (score 12):

I think you need to use an `AnimationSet`.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html):

> Represents a group of Animations that should be played together. The
>   transformation of each individual animation are composed together into
>   a single transform.

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9df24ac25f01cee9/6e0eac7802a541e3) you can see how an `AnimationSet` is supposed to be.

Comment: I think animation set works as combination of animations, not as separate animation on separate views.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question and thought you were performing the animations on the same object.

Comment: Second link is broken, keeps giving me a banned warning

Answer (score 5):

In your Activity

```
ImageView reusableImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
reusableImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag);
reusableImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Animation an =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.yourAnimation);
reusableImageView.startAnimation(an);
```

Then, in yourAnimation.xml define all the animations you want

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:duration="2500" />
<scale
    android:startOffset="2500"
    android:duration="2500"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem is to use an [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) with [Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) objects. If you are worried about backwards compatibility, you can use the NineOldAndroids library to bring the API back all the way to Android 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I solved it starting second animation in onAnimationStart event of the first animation. In my example right layout replacing left one, both of them are moving left at the same time. I use animate property of a View class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate() which is available starting API v.12

```
leftLayout.animate()
    .translationX(-leftLayout.getWidth()) // minus width
    .setDuration(300)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            rightLayout.animate()
                    .translationX(-leftLayout.getWidth()) // minus width
                    .setDuration(300)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            leftLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            leftLayout.setTranslationX(0f); // discarding changes
                            rightLayout.setTranslationX(0f);
                        }
                    });
        }
});
```