# Animation for 4 different images at the same time in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, translate-animation

I have 4 images for animation like translate.But i want to animate them at the same time.No one should not start before or after another one.When i do the below code,it is not starting at the same time.Someone can help me ?

```
Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate);

ImageView image1=myView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
ImageView image2=myView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
ImageView image3=myView.findViewById(R.id.img3);
ImageView image4=myView.findViewById(R.id.img4); 

image1.startAnimation(anim);
image2.startAnimation(anim);
image3.startAnimation(anim);
image4.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: use one `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator` then, or just `AnimatorSet`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10606835/903469

Comment: @sunilsunny Nope. Why? In that answer Link is given for AnimatorSet and you yourself used the same in your answer and asking me if I checked comment or not? Grow up.!

Comment: @sunilsunny What's the [problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75966/proposal-to-solve-the-uncommented-downvote-problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding the `OnAnimationStart` for the animation and starting the next animation inside there. Something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
image1.startAnimation(anim);    


anim.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        switch(counter){
            case 0: image2.startAnimation(anim);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 1: image3.startAnimation(anim);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 2: image4.startAnimation(anim);
                counter++;
        }
    }
image1.startAnimation(anim);
```

and incrementing the counter each time so it starts a different animation.
It's a bit of a jimmy-rig but it's the easiest way I can think to do it.