# android run multiple animations on multiple views parallel

Tags: android, performance, android-animation

Here is the thing:I have a problem in presenting multiple animations
on different views parallel.
I have one button which animates scaling, one image which animates rotation and another two images which animate scaling.
The problem is that on many devices the animations are not smooth,they loose frames. However, when I use only one or two animations the animations are smooth.

edit: 
Here is the animation xml code:

```
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="87" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%">
    <!--
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:startOffset="0"
    -->
</rotate>
```

Comment: @0X0nosugar if the OP is looking to animate multiple views then `ValueAnimator` is unlikely to work. And if I understand his question right, it's similar to [How to start two animations at same time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606053/how-to-start-two-animations-at-same-time-in-android).

Comment: @0X0nosugar no comments should stay I guess, as long as they aren't useless which they don't seem.